# Protractor capabilities.proxy equivalent in puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

I am trying to use puppeteer instead of protractor.

In protractor config, I can use this config for proxy:

```
capabilities: {
  browserName: 'chrome',
  chromeOptions: {
    binary: chromeBin,
    args: [
      '--window-size=1920,1080',
      '--proxy-server=http://my-proxy/',
      '--proxy-bypass-list=http://localhost'
    ]
  },
  proxy: {
    proxyType: 'manual',
    httpProxy: 'http://my-proxy'
  }
}
```

It seems like what's inside chromeOptions matches the settings in puppeteer.launch:

```
browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  executablePath: chromeBin,
  headless,
  args: [
    '--window-size=1920,1080',
    '--proxy-server=http://my-proxy',
    '--proxy-bypass-list=http://localhost'
  ]
});
```

But where do I put the proxy in capabilities? I am not able to launch the page because of proxy issues.

Comment: Can [this section](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#environment-variables) help?

Comment: I tried HTTP_PROXY AND HTTPS_PROXY.  It didn't work. I got Error: net::ERR_NO_SUPPORTED_PROXIES at https://myremotesite

Comment: It turned out I needed to remove '--proxy-server=http://my-proxy/' go get it working...